# Revert back to previous flask session variables when going back a page

Tags: python, session, flask

On a Flask website of mine, I have a session variable called 'thisQuestion' which put simply increments by 1 each time a page is loaded. Basically, the page returns questions from a database and the user can state whether they get the question right or wrong. The session variable increases by 1 to know which question it is on and what question to receive from the database.

```
session['thisQuestion'] += 1
```

However, if I was on the 3rd question page and go back to the 2nd question page, the session variable remains at '3' when I would like it to be at '2'. I would like this to also happen if I was on the 3rd page and go back to '1' on the 1st page.

How would someone go about this?

Comment: Please show some code sample of how you're implementing your increment by 1

Comment: @junnytony I added some code however I didn't know what else was necessary so I improved the question so it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need better state management than that in order to track user going forward and backward or skipping to a different question.

My suggestion is to include the intended question number in the url query string (or to make it more SEO friendly just include the question number in the url)

For ex:

To receive question 1, you'd go to:

```
http://example.com/questions?num=1    # querystring method
http://example.com/questions/1   # using url method (preferred)
```

In flask, your `questions` view will retrieve the appropriate question number (if using the url method)

```
@app.route('/questions/<int:num>')
def questions(num):
    # This part disallows the user from jumping a future question
    # without first answering all the questions that lead up to it
    # i.e a user cannot go from question 1 to question 8 without
    # first answering questions 2 - 7 but once they've answered 
    # question 8 they can jump back to question 2 and then jump to
    # question 9
    highest_num_seen = session.get('highest_num_seen', 1)
    if num > highest_num_seen:
        num = highest_num_seen

    question = db.load_question(num) # Load your question from db

    # update highest_num_seen if and only if it is the next question
    # from what the user last answered
    if num == highest_num_seen + 1:
        session['highest_num_seen'] = num

    render_template('blahblah')
```